# Veritas VM on Unixware, how to remove the "rootdg"?

Tags: unixware, vxvm

I want to remove the rootdg to create my own group, and use 4 disk, this is the situation
System is Unixware 7

```
vxdisk list
DEVICE       TYPE      DISK         GROUP        STATUS
c0b0t1d0s0   sliced    -            -            error
c0b0t2d0s0   sliced    disk01       rootdg       online
c0b0t3d0s0   sliced    -            -            online
c0b0t4d0s0   sliced    -            -            online
c0b0t5d0s0   sliced    -            -            online
```

The command vxdg rmdisk disk01 fail

```
vxdg rmdisk disk01
vxvm:vxdg: ERROR: disassociating disk-media disk01:
    Cannot remove last disk in disk group
```

The commands vxdg deport rootdg fail

```
vxdg deport rootdg
vxvm:vxdg: ERROR: Disk group rootdg: deport failed: Operation not allowed on root disk group
```

the command vxdg destroy rootdg don't exist on Unixware

The command vxdiskunsetup don't exist on Unixware

EDIT1: I don't boot from a rootdg, / is mounted on normal partition on (c0b0t1d0s0 which is not under Veritas vxvm control)

Comment: You want to remove the entire disk group where the OS is located. Wat is the reason you want to destroy DG?

Comment: On Linux I can destroy all lvm groups (except if mounted on / or used by / ) and recreate, in this Veritas version I'm forced to retain the rootdg group with at least one disk. As I know old versions of veritas don't allow to remove the rootdg

Comment: Even in linux you can't remove root VG because you have running OS, mounted filesystem/LV. So the behavior is (more or less) the same.

Comment: No, on Linux you cannot destroy ROOTVG IF is mounted or in use, On Linux I can boot from a normal partition and then use lvm for other stuff (i know is a non sense but you can do it if you want it) I forgot to said on Unixware I'm booting from a normal partition..not from rootdg, otherwise is logical that you cannot remove it because is in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solution" found.
Old versions of Veritas vxvm don't allow to remove the rootdg.
Waiting for a better solution I select this one.